Ag Grid dynamically update cell style based on visible rows changed via set filter
I'm using the pure js version of ag-grid.
my code for cell style looks something like this
cellStyle: params => {
    return getCellColor(params); // my custom func to determine cell color based on the value
}

here is a simplified version of getCellColor(), the actual function is more complex and colors cells in a gradient based on distance from min, max, and average or median.
function getCellColor(params){
   let { min, max, median, average } = calculateMinMaxMedianAverage(params.api, params.colDef.field); // determines these values for all cells in column
   if(params.value > 0){
       return {"color": "rgba(255,255,255,1)"}
   }else{
       return {"color": "rgba(0,0,0,1)"}
   }
}

Now as I mentioned before my real function color codes are based on distance from min, max, and average or median. This means a really high outlier could drastically change the color coding.
My calculateMinMaxMedianAverage() function ultimately loops through each node via params.api.forEachNode. each node seems to have a node.displayed value of true/false which as far as I can tell represents which cells are expected to be visible in the grid (regardless of if it's actually rendered or not due to scrolling virtualization). So it seemed like if excluded nodes with node.displayed == false from the calculateMinMaxMedianAverage() calculations that it should work. However, this didn't seem to be the case as my color-coding results seemed the same either way.
is there something I'm missing?
Some people were asking for a more in-depth example. this is an example that uses my code to determine what shade to color a cell. If you go to this example and sort so that those with the most gold medals are at the top, then you will see a nice green gradient that gets deeper for larger numbers. after sorting like this click the country header, nav to filters, and then search for a disabled united states using the set filter. You'll see lots of the data removed including many of the top scores with the deepest shades of green. When this happens I want to be able to recolor the cells so that once again the topmost value has the same deep green.

need working example to check, provided code is not sufficient please create a working example on aggrid website examples and share back!

@NarenMurali I added an example link to the bottom of the post.

RIP, I feel dumb
So in my example link in the calculateMinMaxMedianAverage() function there is a commented out line
if (node.group === false || node.displayed == false) {
This is the code I thought should work but wasn't. Turn's out my logic was just wrong. it should of been
if (node.group === false && node.displayed == true) {
